# Pie chart properties

Tags: highcharts, seaside

I'm new to Seaside (and Smalltalk) as we are having to use this for a class.  I'm looking for help trying to render a pie chart in Seaside using the Highchart package.  I can get the chart to show up but it displays generic data labels of "slice".  Does anybody know how to trace how to configure the charts properties?

```
renderBarChartOn: html
html div
    script:
        (html
            highchart: [ :chart | 
                chart chart defaultSeriesType: 'pie'.
                chart title text: 'Light On/Off'.
                chart xAxis categories: #('1pm' '2pm' '3pm').
                chart yAxis title text: 'Degrees Fahrenheit'.
                chart
                    series:
                        (Array

                            with:
                                (chart step
                                    data: #(80 20))) ])
```

Have it working now with this:

```
    html div
    script:
        (html
            highchart: [ :chart | 
                chart chart defaultSeriesType: 'pie'.
                chart title text: 'Light On/Off'.
                chart series: (Array with: (chart step data: #(#('On' 80) #(#Off 20)))) ])
```

Comment: I don't know seaside, but you data should be an an array of two-elements arrays, where first one will be name of a slice, and second one should be value. You can't set categories to show "1pm" as slice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  html div
script:
    (html
        highchart: [ :chart | 
            chart chart defaultSeriesType: 'pie'.
            chart title text: 'Light On/Off'.
            chart series: (Array with: (chart step data: #(#('On' 80) #(#Off 20)))) ])
```